# Yocto do_unpack .ipk package

Tags: compilation, yocto, bitbake, unpack

I would like to install some pre compiled .ipk packages in a Yocto image. The installation must be at build time (during the Yocto Image generation not at run time)
The packages will be generated by a Yocto build from the source code of the component itself.
The reason for this is due to code segregation policy.

From the Yocto documentation it seems that this can be done using the bin_package class.

I'm facing some issue during the unpack task. For this post I'm using the nano package as example.

First I compiled Nano from source using the recipe present in meta-openembedded. Then I moved the ipk file generated during compilation to a directory I called prebuild.

Then I created a recipe I called nano2.bb to test the unpack and installation of the .ipk:

```
SRC_URI = "file:///workdir/example2/poky/build/prebuild/nano_6.2-r0_core2-64.ipk;subpath=${BP}"

inherit bin_package
```

When I run $bitbake nano2 I get the following do_unpack error log:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function do_unpack
DEBUG: Executing python function base_do_unpack
NOTE: Unpacking /workdir/example2/poky/build/prebuild/nano_6.2-r0_core2-64.ipk to /workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nano2/1.0-r0/
tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
ERROR: Bitbake Fetcher Error: UnpackError('Unpack command PATH="/workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/workdir/example2/poky/scripts:/workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nano2/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux:/workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nano2/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nano2/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nano2/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nano2/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nano2/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/workdir/example2/poky/bitbake/bin:/workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/hosttools" ar x /workdir/example2/poky/build/prebuild/nano_6.2-r0_core2-64.ipk data.tar.xz && tar --extract --no-same-owner -p -f data.tar.xz && rm data.tar.xz failed with return value 2', 'file:///workdir/example2/poky/build/prebuild/nano_6.2-r0_core2-64.ipk;subpath=nano2-1.0')
DEBUG: Python function base_do_unpack finished
DEBUG: Python function do_unpack finished
```

The file nano_6.2-r0_core2-64.ipk exists:
ls /workdir/example2/poky/build/prebuild/nano_6.2-r0_core2-64.ipk -la
-rw-r--r-- 1 pokyuser pokyuser 172444 Nov  8 13:24 /workdir/example2/poky/build/prebuild/nano_6.2-r0_core2-64.ipk

and inside the folder /workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nano2/1.0-r0/
ls /workdir/example2/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/nano2/1.0-r0/ -la
total 184
drwxr-xr-x 4 pokyuser pokyuser   4096 Nov  8 14:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 pokyuser pokyuser   4096 Nov  8 13:59 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 pokyuser pokyuser 171808 Nov  8 14:03 data.tar.xz
drwxr-xr-x 2 pokyuser pokyuser   4096 Nov  8 14:03 nano2-1.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 pokyuser pokyuser   4096 Nov  8 14:03 temp

Also if I run manualy in the shell the command do_unpack is running it gives me no error!
ar x /workdir/example2/poky/build/prebuild/nano_6.2-r0_core2-64.ipk data.tar.xz && tar --extract --no-same-owner -p -f data.tar.xz && rm data.tar.xz

A'm I missing something?
Any ideas on how to debug the root cause?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for this issue is that by default the "xz" utility is not white listed in HOSTTOOLS.
xz is used to extract the .ipk content.

Adding in local.conf the line below solves the problem

```
# For Yocto 4 Kirkstone
HOSTTOOLS:append = " xz"
```

The Yocto IRC guys were very helpful!